# It's possible limit some string formatters on fzaninotto Faker

Tags: php, laravel-5, faker

I'm working with this library, and I've encountered a problem I have failed to solve.

I like some fields with limit size, such userName (Faker\Provider\Internet). I think ot's not good idea use string with 255 for this field and like limit to 15.

After some crash on seed generation for my table i read code.

```
protected static $userNameFormats = array(
        '{{lastName}}.{{firstName}}',
        '{{firstName}}.{{lastName}}',
        '{{firstName}}##',
        '?{{lastName}}',
    );
public function userName()
    {
        $format = static::randomElement(static::$userNameFormats);
        $username = static::bothify($this->generator->parse($format));

        return strtolower(static::transliterate($username));
    }
```

For use with my program, i think create a fork. On this fork modify code

```
protected static $userNickFormats = array(
       '{{firstName}}',
       '{{firstName}}#',
       '{{firstName}}##',
       '{{firstName}}###',
       '?{{lastName}}##',
    );


public function userNick($limit = 15)
    {
        $format = static::randomElement(static::$userNickFormats);
        $username = static::bothify($this->generator->parse($format));
        while (strlen($username) > $limit) {
            $username = static::bothify($this->generator->parse($format));
        }

        return strtolower(static::transliterate($username));
    }
```

I think there is a best way for this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure a fork of Faker is the easiest way to go about this.

Consider just creating your own Provider class and add it to faker.
See [the documentation](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker#faker-internals-understanding-providers).

In your case it might look something like this (code blatantly copied from the docs):

*userNickProvider.php*

```
<?php

class UserNick extends \Faker\Provider\Base
{
    protected static $userNickFormats = array(
       '{{firstName}}',
       '{{firstName}}#',
       '{{firstName}}##',
       '{{firstName}}###',
       '?{{lastName}}##',
    );


    public function userNick()
    {
        $format = static::randomElement(static::$userNickFormats);
        $username = static::bothify($this->generator->parse($format));

        return strtolower(static::transliterate($username));
    }    
}
```

As for the limit you need, there is a modifier called `valid()` you can use with any of the faker methods. You just supply a function that returns a bool deciding if the generated value is a valid one, otherwise it generates another and so on. So you don't have to do this in your provider function.

First the validator:

```
$max15 = function($string) {
    return mb_strlen($string) <= 15;
};
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
$faker = new Faker\Generator();
$faker->addProvider(new UserNick($faker));

$name = $faker->valid($max15)->userNick;
```

In summary:
You don't have to fork Faker to get what you want, just write your own Provider.